# Modify CSS after hover effect on mobile

Tags: html, jquery, css

I am working on a website where one of the sessions has a click effect. Basically the text body is hidden and when clicking on  it expands showing the hidden text as you can see in the image:

[Before Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TU0uX.png)

[After Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LmXl.png)

In CSS, basically the text element has a height of 30px and after: hover it has 300px.

```css
.portfolio_text{
        height:30px;
}
#ho_nf:hover .portfolio_text {
        height: 200px;
        padding: 20px 14px;
        overflow: visible;
       
    }
```

Portfolio_text returns to normal height if I click outside the element's Div or click on another element in the list of 6.

What I need is to be able to return the text to the size of 30 by clicking on the close icon that I added in the left corner to see the background image again.

I tried with JQuery but it didn't work and I need it only on mobile because the Desktop is based on: hover and removing the mouse it goes back to the normal state.

Answer (score 0):

There is no `:hover` pseudo-element for mobile since there is no cursor.

Try using `:active`.